Slide edge to opposite edge - geometry nodes
I'm working on sliding the edges of a cube to the opposite side using geometry nodes.
I almost have the solution; it works by sliding the factor of the mix, but there is one problem: when the edge slides to the other side, it scales to zero.
Could you help me fix the nodes so that it slides completely to the other side?
Blender 3.6.9

You don't want to sample the edge, instead you want to sample the vertices. It would be a bit more complicated, as you need to adjust 2 vertices instead of 1 edge, but I think this is the way. In fact, I think Set Position works on the vertex domain, so currently both vertices of 9 go to the position of the edge 6.

@Lutzi Thanks, you're right, it works this way. It doesn't look too good, but it works! :)
But I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution, if anyone has a good idea for this, please share it here, thanks! Here is my solution:
link

I agree with @Lutzi here, the Set Position node works on the vertex domain. Using the edge index for the Selection input selects both vertices of the edge with index 9. Then sampling the position of edge 6 gets the center of the edge, then the Set Position node moves both vertices to the center.
